# Automatic SVN backup

Tags: svn, raspberry-pi, nas

I want to use SVN to make a backup of my system, using Raspberry pi.

There is a NAS, where some users make changes in a folder, and do a 'backup' to SVN repo. I have SVN repo set up, and already checked out the files, but if I make changes over samba, the commit will not affect the repo. I want to make automatic copy(commit) of them. I want to have an automatic backup of the files, maybe with crontab which run every 1 hour, or so.

There is no option to commit every files with a single name, I want to make it automatically.

If there will be an automatic backup with tar.gz, send it over maybe FTP, the files size will be much more, than the regular SVN, and there will be no version control.

I tried http://gael-varoquaux.info/computers/svnautocommit/, but it has a lot of bug.

Comment: Subversion **is not designed to be used as a backup system**. There are many free backup systems/utilities which will do what you're looking for, and do it better.

Answer (score 1):

svnsync is what you want. You set it up with a source and destination repo, and from them on, simply call the svnsync command again. It'll replay all commits made since the last time it ran to the destination repo.

The redbook has the information to get this going. Remember, you do need to create a blank destination repo for svnsync to copy into, and you'll have to set the hooks to allow propchanges.

Comment: svnsync is not only svn repo's mirrorring? I have no svn repo on the NAS(samba) server.

Comment: in that case, just use svnrdump or svnhotcopy - the redbook has all details.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to track changes to the server (such as /etc, /usr/local, etc.), and can write to a SVN repo, then you should look at [FSVS](http://fsvs.stage.tigris.org/).

- No need for .svn folders on the server being version controlled
- Efficient across the wire because it uses SVN
- Makes it easy to browse the repo to see how a particular file has changed over time
- Can be used as a notes function to remind you why you made a change

I would still suggest that you use, in addition, some sort of backup-oriented software like [borg](https://github.com/borgbackup/borg).